# Is it possible to install a solid state drive into a Sun Ultra 40 M2 workstation?

Tags: ssd, sata, sun

Our [Sun Ultra 40 M2 workstations](http://www.sun.com/desktop/workstation/ultra40/) came with SAS drives, but my understanding is that the backplane will support both SAS and SATA. Sun's docs specify a very limited number of supported drives, but I'm wondering if anyone has actual experience installing a solid state drive. We're looking at the [Corsair P128,](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233087) but any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That model will definitely support 3.5" SATA disks so if you buy wisely you'll be able to fit SSDs inside, get them connected correctly and use them. That said be aware that generally speaking a regular disk will rarely, if ever, reach it's highest temperature, they tend to top-out at about 55 degrees centigrade, in my own tests of SSDs inside servers I've seen SSDs hit, and stay around, 70 degrees under load - and not all servers or disk enclosures are built to scrub that kind of heat - I just wanted you to be aware.

Answer (score 0):

Sun like most vendors doesn't want you to install third party equipment if they can help it, that being said SAS and SATA are both standards and most of the solid state drives I have used over the years are standards compliant and will slot right in without any problems.

Comment: So do you need to get a SATA backplane to slot in a SATA SSD or can you just plug into the Ultra 40 motherboard?

Comment: I think the ultra 40 motherboards are SATA compatible (as thats the standard drive) and you can plug it in. But to make sure find out what the controller is from Sun. I don't have this hardware on hand.